# Why I can assign objectA to objectB and change objectA's property by changing objectB in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, object

In JavaScript,

I just found that

```
var a = {};
a.name = "132";
var b = a;
console.log(b);
b.name = "efg";
console.log(a);//**display "123","efg"**
```

It seems like I can assign objectA to objectB and change objectA's property by changing objectB in Javascript.

But this will **not** work:

```
var aa = 1;
var bb = aa;
console.log(bb);
bb = 2;
console.log(aa);//**display "1","1"**
```

I just wonder why this happend?

JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Pencil_Case/2wxxmgvx/3/

Comment: do some research before asking

Comment: I can't think of an object oriented system where this *doesn't* happen.

Comment: @raghavendra well, I  tried to look up in some books. just failed. I am just a rookie. sorry

Comment: @David Awkward. I just began learning programming. Sorry.

Comment: @Pencil_Case: One thing to be *really* careful of as a result of this is when you modify objects *inside of functions/methods*, because it can have unexpected and unintended side-effects to the objects *outside* of those methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because when you assign an object to another, it is not copied, only the reference is given.

In Javascript, *Composite data types*(Object, array) are **copied by reference**

```
var b = a; // Get the reference of a and assign to b
```

If you want to get copy of object use [`assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

```
var b = Object.assign({}, a);
```

Comment: So it only happens to an object？ and only in javascript？

Comment: @Pencil_Case This happens for `Objects`, `array` in javascript is `Object`

Comment: @Pencil_Case This is normal for many object oriented programming (OOP) languages, not just Javascript.

Comment: @jazZRo A great lesson.Thx.